# Infragistics Drag and Drop Tree Paging

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, infragistics

My client wants me to implement paging and search capabilities for data inserted into a tree.  I am using Infragistics [see sample](http://www.igniteui.com/tree/drag-and-drop-single-tree) for viewing hierarchical data.

Are there are any configurations settings for paging and search implementation provided for this tree view?  I plan to display the set of records based on the page number in custom paging manner.  I know how to do this, but I wonder whether I am missing any configuration setting to make this easier, or even trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with aspx, this may help you,

add the behavior section to your TreeGrid section :

```
<Behaviors>
<Paging PagerAppearance="Bottom" PageSize="10" Enabled="true" />
</Behaviors>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am using html/jquery not aspx.  Please let me know if you find anything which can work with this.